# Can AEM share crypto library/key to other system?

Tags: encryption, aes, aem

Basically in AEM I would want to encrypt some text using AEM CryptoSupport and pass the encrypted key to other system(say ABC system), then the ABC system to decrypt the key to do some action.

AEM can share Adobe Granite Crypto Support 0.0.8 jar to ABC system to do encrypt/decrypt but I wonder how does AEM share HMAC and Master file to other system to decrypt? Is this possible ? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have to share the jar with them. AEM CryptoSupport uses AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding for encryption. As long as both systems use a known key and scheme you should be able to encrypt/decrypt without having to use the same jar. AEM Cryptosupport can be used with a key other than the one generated by AEM.

[CryptoSupport#encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] plainText)](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/crypto/CryptoSupport.html#encrypt(byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D))

The way to generate encryption key bytes is by using

`CryptoSupport.hmac_256(shared_hash_key, shared_secret)`

This allows you to come up with a shared key to use with the other system without having to expose AEMs keys.

To decrypt on the other system use the same hash key and secret. The part after ':' in output from CryptoSupport.encrypt is the IV.

Comment: Are you sure other system can decrypt the public key ? I heard that AEM uses  symmetric cryptography which should not be shared. We may need to use  asymmetric cryptography to handle this use case.

Comment: crypto support uses symmetric keys. You can implement your own encryption service to use asymmetric keys.

Comment: Thank. Yeah, we would need to with asymmetric